# Dictionary to CSV with Pandas to_csv and reload it with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have created a list of dictionaries with roughly 60 columns each.
Each one has the same number of columns.

```
list = [dict1, dict2, ...]
dict1 = {c1: 1, c2:0.15, c3:5, c4:[Numpy Array of 50x50], c5:[Numpy Array of 50x50], c6:[Numpy Array of 50x50]}
dict2 = {c1: 2, c2:0.25, c3:3, c4:[Numpy Array of 50x50], c5:[Numpy Array of 50x50], c6:[Numpy Array of 50x50]}
...

pandas_dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list)
pandas_dataset.to_csv('test.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False)
```

With the code above, the output of the Numpy Arrays is like this :
50,0.12,not_weld_seam,"[34695  36237  37779  39321 ...]"

After using pd.read_csv('test.csv'), the Numpy Arrays are considered as string and not arrays.
Could you advise me a solution ?
Thank you in advance

Among these All these columns

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name. It is built-in class name in python

Comment: Yes sure, my fault, it is not the same in my code only for the question.

Comment: after `df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')` can you print the output of `df2.info()`. I tried at my side. It was fine, not strings.

Comment: Instead of pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_test), I also tried pd.DataFrame(list_test).
Same output issue

Comment: df2.info() gives me the following data :
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 951 entries, 0 to 950
Data columns (total 58 columns):
Column_Size  951 non-null int64
Gaussian_Filter  951 non-null float64
Image_Class_Name  951 non-null object
Image_Grayscale   951 non-null object
Image_Id   951 non-null int64
Image_RGB  951 non-null object
Image_Segmentation   951 non-null object
Row_Size   951 non-null int64
WeldSeam_0_MidLine_keypoint_x  951 non-null float64
WeldSeam_0_Out Negative_Side_keypoint_x 951 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(51), int64(3), object(4)

Comment: Image_Grayscale, Image_RGB, Image_Segmentation are my Numpy Arrays

Comment: it is `object` not `string`

Comment: object valued (list, array, etc) cells do not play very well with `csv` since the format is jsut text file. Consider `df.to_pickle()` and `pd.read_pickle` instead.

Comment: Yes it is string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.array2string()` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html)
If your numpy array is **decimal** number then set the precision using `precision=2`

```
np.array2string(x, precision=2, separator=',')
```

---

Here is an example way to do it

```py
dict1 = {'c1': 1, 'c2':0.15, 'c3':5, 'c4':np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), 'c5':np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'c6':np.array([1,2,3,4])}
dict2 = {'c1': 1, 'c2':0.15, 'c3':5, 'c4':np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'c5':np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'c6':np.array([1,2,3,4])}
l = [dict1, dict2,]

# convert numpy array to string
df['c4'] = df['c4'].apply(lambda x: np.array2string(x, separator=','))
df['c5'] = df['c5'].apply(lambda x: np.array2string(x, separator=','))
df['c6'] = df['c6'].apply(lambda x: np.array2string(x, separator=','))

# write it to csv
df.to_csv('temp.csv',mode='w', header=True, index=False)

# read it to csv
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
# convert it back to numpy array
df['c4'] = df['c4'].apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)))
df['c5'] = df['c5'].apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)))
df['c6'] = df['c6'].apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)))
```